# Avoid duplicating data in NSMutable array

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsarray

I have app where data after pushing `viewcontroller` (multiple times) collects in  the `NSMutableArray`

```
nextController.pathArray = self.pathArray;
```

How to prevent duplicating data from `pathArray` in `nextController.pathArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `NSMutableSet` and add your object there as well. Before adding items to your mutable array check first before you add it if it exist in the set. Where ever your adding your data should look something like this example:

```
if (![set containsObject:data])
{
   [set addObject:data];
   [self.pathArray addObject:data
}
```

If you aren't concern about arrangement for you collection I would suggestion of using a `NSMutableSet` instead of `NSMutableArray` and converting it back to a mutable array when changing view controllers like so:

```
      nextController.pathArray = self.set.allObjects.mutableCopy;
```

Comment: But NSMutableSet declares the programmatic interface to an unordered collection of objects. I need my objects to be ordered in NSMutableArray.

Comment: you could return it like this `nextController.pathArray = self.mutableSet.allObjects;`  allObjects returns a ordered array